# Creating a post with guttenberg content using the WP-REST-API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using the wp rest api for adding posts to my site from another app. Therefore I use `POST /wp-json/wp/v2/seminar` where `seminar` is my custom post type. In the post data I set `content` to some text.

The Problem is that Wordpress creates a block with the tinyMce editor instead of using the default guttenberg paragraph block (see images below).

What is created:
[Image of Tinymce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6b27.png)

What I want to be created:
[Image of paragraph editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpavC.png)

Does someone know  a way to make wordpress creating the paragraph insted of the tinymce block?

Comment: Please add code of guttenberg paragraph block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make content like this

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>my content text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```